# Could not invoke RN.createPublicClientApplication

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to configure the Azure AD B2C application for react native and using [this lib](https://github.com/stashenergy/react-native-msal) for react-native. It is working for IOS but for android, I am facing error below.
I have double checked the package name and signature hash.

I have also checked my redirect url in the `msalConfigurationfile.json` and that is same as, on the azure portal and `androidmanifest.xml`.
well, i have configure the configuration below

in android > app > src > main > assets > msal_config.json

```
{
    "client_id": "My_client-id",
    "authorization_user_agent": "DEFAULT",
    "redirect_uri": "msauth://com.myPackegeName/M09kWwKnLGHKWwoswsUy5csbgBRxjM%3D",
    "account_mode": "MULTIPLE",
    "broker_redirect_uri_registered": true,
    "authorities" : [
        {
          "type": "B2C",
          "authority_url": "https://domain.b2clogin.com/tfp/compnay.onmicrosoft.com/",
          "default": true
        }
      ]
   
}
```

[image]

Comment: Share your MSAL config, what authority is set?

Comment: in android > app > src > main > assets > msal_config.json

{
    "client_id": "My_client-id",
    "authorization_user_agent": "DEFAULT",
    "redirect_uri": "msauth://com.myPackegeName/M74kWwKnLGHLWwvswsUc7csggBRxjM%3D",
    "account_mode": "MULTIPLE",
    "broker_redirect_uri_registered": true,
    "authorities" : [
        {
          "type": "B2C",
          "authority_url": "https://domain.b2clogin.com/tfp/compnay.onmicrosoft.com/",
          "default": true
        }
      ]
   
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this issue by changing `"broker_redirect_uri_registered": true,` to `"broker_redirect_uri_registered": false,`